# EDMX migrating from webservice to local access

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, sql-server-ce, edmx

Right now I have the following architecture:

- WPF client app to display some data
- Self hosted service containing access to a database (self hosted as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx))
- service uses edmx file to describe database (and generate it)
- client accesses the host via wcf
- generated a proxy for use with the client (with SvcUtil from running Host)

Due to new requirements the database is now local on each machine.

The self hosted service requires `elevated rights` to run,
but not every possible user of my application can have those rights.

Is it possible to create (at best generate) an assembly that runs in the client context to
access the database? (e.g. a `dll`, so I do not need the host).

Are there any better possibilities?

Any idea on creating an assembly for local access from EDMX and / or generating a proxy for my client is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did about it:

The client got a `Repository` to access the database.

The database access itself is done in a new assembly, which only does that
and provides a `DatabaseContext` class, which is actually a wrapper around
the EF methods.

The client-repository has an instance of the `DatabaseContext` and
provides just `CRUD` methods to access it.